# Need to integrate a css line block in this message form section

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I asked some questions about this approach. I need to create a responsive contact form in WordPress with this yellow line. Have you some tips to crea†e it. Do I play with border :before :after? Thank you for your help

[image]

Comment: What have you already done ?

Comment: Nothing at this moment.